# Why comparison-based sorting algorithm have lower bound of Ω(n log n) for its worst-case running time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, comparison

I get that any comparison-based sorting algorithm has a lower bound of Ω(n log n) for its worst-case running time, but why is it so? Is there anyway I can prove it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the theory of computation, not programming. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might want to read this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list

Comment: @Raymond The FAQ explicitly says "a software algorithm", so while you might be right that it's about computation theory, it's still clearly within the bounds of what SO allows, unless there's a Meta post specifically saying that doesn't apply to cs.se. I'm a moderator on SQA , but we don't automatically VTC/VTMigrate all testing/selenium related questions there.

Comment: @corsiKa SO is for "[practical, detailed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)." Theory of computation is a theoretical problem, not a practical one. A practical problem about a software algorithm would be "I can't get this algorithm to work."

Comment: @Raymond You're ANDing the criteria. You should be ORing those criteria.

Comment: @corsiKa From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: @remyabel I'm not saying this is a perfect question. I'm not sure if it should be closed or not. What I am saying is the reason Raymond gave for it being closed is not a valid one.

Comment: @corsika Agreed. There is a meta discussion about hastily moving questions to other sites when it should just be closed, period.

Comment: @corsiKa Before they changed the "Close" options, it was clearer. One of the reasons for closing was "not practical." Obviously, the conditions are ANDed. Or are you saying it's okay to ask a practical, unanswerable question?

Comment: @corsiKa Even if you think it's on-topic, it's very much a duplicate. [Lower bound of comparison-based sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15625150/), [Why is the lower bound for the time complexity of comparison-based sort algorithms O(n log n)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1891506/), and probably others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are n! permutations on n objects. A sorting algorithm will need to perform different actions on each of the n! permutations to get them back into order. A sorting algorithm which tests k comparisons can only see 2^k different results, so we need to have 2^k >= n! to have it do something different on each of the n! permutations. If you use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation for n! and neglect all but the first term, you will end up with n log n comparisons. See for example http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15211/fall.97/www/recitations/rec1006